# Custom scheduler for Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I want to create a replica of the existing fair / capacity scheduler in Hadoop and then make some changes. Any idea anybody? Please help.
I downloaded the `hadoop-2.6.0-src` source code, and see the `FairScheduler.java` source at the following path:

```
\hadoop-2.6.0-src\hadoop-yarn-project\hadoop-yarn\hadoop-yarn-server\hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager\src\main\java\org\apache\hadoop\yarn\server\resourcemanager\scheduler\fair
```

But, guess there are many related class files. Do I have to copy all of them, rename and create a new project? Please help as I am not a java guy.

Answer (score 0):

Manisha, you could try to extend the already existent `FairScheduler` class, creating a `MyFairScheduler` and adding those changes you talk about in the required methods. Then, the new class can be build and packaged into a jar file that must be put into the classpath in order it can be used.